# .Net Service Crashes in Unmanaged Thread With Unknown Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, threadpool

A VB.Net service is crashing on a number of client systems and I'm unsure exactly why.  They all produce the same exception code and stack trace:

```
Unknown exception - code c000070a (first/second chance not available)
ntdll!TppRaiseHandleStatus+0x91
ntdll!TppSetupNextWait+0xa51fd
ntdll!TpSetWaitEx+0xaa
ntdll!EtwpNotificationThread+0x85
ntdll!TppExecuteWaitCallback+0x91
ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x9ae
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

The stack trace and an article titled 'What does this crash in TppRaiseHandleStatus mean?' (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160115-00/?p=92861) points to a problem with some waiting event.  Trouble is the trace and dump aren't very helpful other than that and unfortunately it sometimes takes days for a crash to occur so it's not easily reproducible.

This service doesn't use many Wait/WaitAny calls but most of the code that does use Waits have been around for a long time and with these crashes only starting recently I have doubts it's any of that code.

Has anyone else run into this and if so, how did you resolve it?  Thanks.

Comment: First of all, I would start to check what has changed since the first crashes... Then if you can spot that out, please edit your question and add the code that has been changed...

Comment: Well unfortunately my version control isn't very good so I don't easily have that but even if I did, there would be way too much to post anyway.  It'd be ideal if I could figure it out through the dump so if you have any suggestions there let me know.

Comment: Well as pointed out by your linked article, some thread performed a wait and it didn't go well... Maybe something else destroyed or ended a thread while it was waiting...

Comment: The joy of non-deterministic garbage collection. This looks like you forgot to keep a reference to a wait primitive around, while still waiting on it. Once the finalizer gets around to close the native resource, things start to go downhill. Try to apply more memory pressure on the process, to force the GC (and finalizer) to run more frequently. This may give you a chance to reproduce the crash.